# Hazelcast global advanced features

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hazelcast

I am analyzing JCache reference implementations and I have found the Hazelcast. So questions are:

1. Is there a way of using Hazelcast with Hibernate and set different expiration values for different jpa entities? EHCache supports it, but I didn't manage to get example for Hazelcast.
2. Does Hazelcast support caching to file system and caching to the database?
3. Is it good idea to use it as a local cache only? Isn't it heavyweight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Hazelcast configuration allows you to define named map areas, or in Hibernate speak regions.  When you specify `@Cache` on an entity, the region name is resolved as the fully qualified class name of the entity unless you specify the `region` attribute yourself.

In your Hazelcast configuration, you often have something like the following taken from the Hazelcast documentation:

```
<hazelcast>
  <map name="com.company.feature.domain.SomeEntityClass">
    <time-to-live-seconds>0</time-to-live-seconds>
    <max-idle-seconds>0</max-idle-seconds>
    <eviction-policy>LRU</eviction-policy>
    <max-size policy="PER_NODE">5000</max-size>
    <eviction-percentage>25</eviction-percentage>
    <min-eviction-check-millis>100</min-eviction-check-millis>
  </map>
</hazelcast>
```

Each map area allows you to define how the region is to be evicted.  Unless you define an eviction policy or you manually remove elements from the cache, Hazelcast will cache them indefinitely.  You're welcomed to read the Hazelcast documentation that describes what each of the various configuration properties represent and their valid value sets.

As for persistence, yes Hazelcast allows you to define a `<mapstore/>` configuration where you specify `MapStore` and `MapLoader` implementations so you can persist the cache to your needs.

Lastly, I cannot necessarily speak to the *heavyweight* factor of Hazelcast.  Perhaps others can chime in on this point.

My suggestion here would be to test it and other alternatives in the market and profile which works best for your needs from a performance and scability perspective weighed against the flexibility and rigidness it takes to configure & maintain.